# How to animate a webview when tapping and changing URL on it in Nativescript?

Tags: ios, url, events, webview, nativescript

Hello Nativescript community. Here's my problem :

**What I need to do**

I'm trying to animate a webview (opacity) to make it disappear ONLY when webview url change (not with a backtotop for example).

**Playground**

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=7yxxiH

**Issues**

It works fine on Android, **but NOT on iOS**, the webview disappear, appear and disappear again multiple times, to stay finally with the opacity to 0.

**Code used**

```
function onWebviewTape(args) {

  var page = args.object.page;
  var webview = page.getViewById("myWebView");

  webview.on(webViewModule.WebView.loadStartedEvent, (args) => {
    webview.animate({
      opacity: 0,
      duration: 100,
      delay: 0
    });
    console.log('webview disappear');
  });

  webview.on(webViewModule.WebView.loadFinishedEvent, (args) => {
    webview.animate({
      opacity: 1,
      duration: 100
    });
    console.log('webview appear');
  });


}
exports.onWebviewTape = onWebviewTape;
```

**Console log**

```
[iPhone de hugo]: webview disappear
[iPhone de hugo]: webview appear
[iPhone de hugo]: webview disappear
[iPhone de hugo]: webview disappear
[iPhone de hugo]: webview disappear
[iPhone de hugo]: webview disappear
[iPhone de hugo]: webview disappear
[Galaxy S8]: webview disappear
[Galaxy S8]: webview appear
```

Comment: I used a var to execute ONE time the function

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=7yxxiH&v=2

It works fine, it looks like a temporary, alternative solution

Comment: I guess it may be an issue specific to Samsung / OS version, I was not able to reproduce it with the same Playground on Moto G5 Plus / Android 8.1. Did you try on other devices / OS versions than the Galaxy S8?

Comment: Hi Manoj, it's an iOS issue. All is perfect with Android.

Comment: Sorry I was confused with your question "It works fine on Android, **but on Android**", may be relevant tags might help.

Comment: My bad. I edited the answer

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to live with the workaround as WKWebView on iOS fires the load started event not only for the actual url to be loaded but also for any resource that has to be loaded within the web page, so it gets triggered multiple times. If you prefer a better solution you might have to override the class WKNavigationDelegate implementation and use [webView:didCommitNavigation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455635-webview?language=objc) callback.